# How to model a time-discrete heat equation on a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, laplacian

I would like to know how one can set up a time-discrete model for the heat equation on a graph? 
Is this problem using the heat kernel equation on a graph?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you expect from your model. If you take the Laplacian of a graph and simply consider its powers, then this system will hardly converge to equilibrium, since the largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian is (approximately) the maximal degree of the graph. However, if you normalize it by introducing the *normalized Laplacian* $D^{-1}A$, where $D$ is the diagonal degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then this matrix has spectrum contained in the interval $[-1,1]$ and hence it can be regarded as a well-behaved transition matrix. You eventually end up with a classical random walk on a graph, though: I am not sure whether this is what you were really looking after.

Comment: @DelioMungnolo: Because I aim at measuring temperature in some arbitrary vertices after modeling, then I guess(not sure) this wont lead to what I have in mind(edge-based identification problem). I would like to use incidence matrix and, consequently, one can use Laplacian matrix as well.

Comment: I see. But then why won't you use a time-continuous model? Then the solution would be given by the semigroup generated by the Laplacian (with negative sign if you want to converge towards equilibrium).